# can't connect any bluetooth device after updating from 22.04 to 22.10 ubuntu

Tags: sound, bluetooth, 22.10

i still can pair with any device, but if i try connect to speakers or my phone, it immediately disconnect and trying to connect again.

i use "bluetoothctl" console program to connect and got this error:

[bluetooth]# connect 00:9E:C8:F5:25:E6

Attempting to connect to 00:9E:C8:F5:25:E6

Failed to connect: org.bluez.Error.Failed br-connection-profile-unavailable

Comment: i think i find a solve my problem
i enter command 
$systemctl --user start pulseaudio
in console and problem solve
not sure that correct solving but it works

Comment: i add this command in "startup application" program and now it look like it work correctly

Comment: Thanks @philip, it solved problem on my computer too