# 22.04 to 22.10 upgrade - bluetooth no longer turns on

Tags: bluetooth, 22.10

I upgraded from 22.04 to 22.10 a couple days ago, had some initial issues related to GDM, and now bluetooth doesn't seem to turn on - meaning I can't use my keyboard or trackpad unless over usb.

I've tried:

- rebooting. still happens
- turning bluetooth on from settings menu and quick settings (see screenshot) - stays stuck at off.
- running `bluetoothctl` which just says `Agent Registered`
- looking at [can't connect any bluetooth device after updating from 22.04 to 22.10 ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1436812/cant-connect-any-bluetooth-device-after-updating-from-22-04-to-22-10-ubuntu) but their issue seemed different.
- searching around in journalctl, can't find anything under searching 'bluetooth', is there something else to look for?

Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I did have the same problem: Bluetooth audio did not work anymore after upgrade to Ubuntu 22.10.

All the suggested checks did not show any problems -- bluetooth was enabled, not blocked etc.

First note that Ubuntu 22.10 has replace the old sound server Pulseaudio with Pipewire.

Install the libraries for the PipeWire multimedia server - bluetooth plugins

`sudo apt install libspa-0.2-bluetooth`

after that I had to restart pipewire (or do a restart)

`systemctl --user restart pipewire`

sources:

- https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/xjbqtg/no_bluetooth_audio_device_after_upgrade_to_2210/
- https://askubuntu.com/a/1339897/17250

Answer (score 0):

Check if the bluetooth radio is not blocked by software/hardware switches by running `rfkill`

The output should be something like

```
$ rfkill
ID TYPE      DEVICE                   SOFT      HARD
 0 bluetooth tpacpi_bluetooth_sw unblocked unblocked
 2 wlan      phy0                unblocked unblocked
14 bluetooth hci0                unblocked unblocked
```

If it's soft-blocked, you should be able to unblock it with `rfkill unblock bluetooth`.  If it's hard-blocked, look for a physical switch on your laptop.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Tried running rfkill, was softblocked, then ran `rfkill unblock bluetooth` and `rfkill` after which showed unblocked. Still couldn't enable bluetooth from gnome settings though. Rebooted, ran `rfkill` to make sure it still said unblocked, still can't enable bluetooth from gnome though. May need to search/file an issue in gnome 43 and/or ubuntu 22.10.

Answer (score 0):

While not a full answer, I ended up observing that I switched from having bluetooth issues to having Wifi issues after reinstalling Windows 10 & Linux, and resolved the wifi issues by booting into Windows then turning off Wifi then going back into Linux to turn it back on, per answer in https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/724043/200022

There's a possibility this issue with bluetooth may be similarly resolved this way for anyone else running a dual-boot setup.

Answer (score 0):

Open a Terminal.

Enter "bluetoothctl"

Then enter "scan on"

Give it a minute and your bluetooth devices should now show upp in the Bluetooth Manager and you will be able to connect them.  Your system should remmeber your devices on reboot.